# YQL Twitter timeline Rate limit exceeded. workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter, yql

I am looking for a solution/advice in my situation:

I want to use YQL for getting twitter timeline feeds,

**Feed example:**

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=NynasBo&count=2

Here is my YQL query string:

```
select * from json where url="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=NynasBo&count=2"
```

but because twitter has limitation on number of calls of course i get pretty much all the time "**Rate limit exceeded**", because a lots of users are using yahoo domain name.

I want and advice how can a make have a solution or workaround in this situation, like:

change domain name, 
use different tables,
different way to get feeds,
something else, because .. etc

Unfortunately I do not have a big experience with YQL :(.

PS:

*I use just client side code (javascript/jQuery)*

**Why I need in this cae to use YQL**:

I want to mush up about 10-15 users timeline in one, and for that I have to make 10-15 AJAX call, where YQl has **yql.query.multi** tabe which is a perfect solution for me, I can combine all these query in one and use 1 AJAX call.

I appreciate any help.

*Sorry for my English*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

Take a look at "How Do I Get Started" section on the page: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ and get a access key. You might need an oauth library.

If you don't have an access key the "Per IP rate limit" applies. From the webpage above, the rate limits are as follows:

Usage Limits
Per application limit (identified by your Access Key): 100,000 calls per day
Per IP limits: /v1/public/*: 2,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/*: 20,000 calls per hour